# Finished JavaScript calculator with mysterious flaw

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

I've tried making this calculator for some time now and to me everything looks just right but it won't work no matter how many times I've gone over the code. I'm going mad over this! How can this not work? Nothing happens when I hit Calculate! Please help me with this one!

Here's the JavaScript:

```
function calc() {
    var num1, num2;
    var sign = "+";
    var result;

    function getNum1() {
        num1 = document.getElementById('num1').value;
        return Number(num1);
    }
    function getNum2() {
        num2 = document.getElementById('num2').value;
        return Number(num2);
    }
    function getSign() {
        sign = document.getElementById('sign').value;
        return sign;
    }
    function setResult() {
        document.getElementById('result').value = result;
    }
    function doCalc() {

        var num1 = getNum1();
        var num2 = getNum2();

        if(getSign() == "*") {
            result = num1 * num2; 
        }else if(getSign() == "/") {
            result = num1 / num2;
        }else if(getSign() == "-") {
            result = num1 - num2; 
        }else{
            result = num1 + num2;
        }
        setResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: Considering we don't have all the code, it may continue to be "mysterious". Is `calc()` being invoked? (add alert/or console.log)

Comment: yes calc is being invoked
 
<input type="text" id="num1" size="1" /> 
<select id="sign"> 
<option value="*">×</option> 
<option value="/">÷</option> 
<option value="-">-</option> 
<option value="+">+</option> 
</select> 
<input type="text" id="num2" size="1"/> 
<input type="button" value="Calculate" id="btn" onClick="calc();" /> Answere: <input type="text" id="result" size="5"/>

Comment: Does it invoke `doCacl()`? see @thesystem's answer.

Comment: it did not! doCalc(); did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

If you're invoking `doCalc()`, it's not reachable because it's scoped inside the `calc()` function.

If you're invoking `calc()`, it doesn't do anything because it never invokes `doCalc()`.

If you add a `doCalc()` invocation to the end of the `calc()` function, and if your `calc()` function is reachable, it'll work.

Comment: <input type="text" id="num1" size="1" />
<select id="sign">
<option value="*">×</option>
<option value="/">÷</option>
<option value="-">-</option>
<option value="+">+</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="num2" size="1"/>

<input type="button" value="Calculate" id="btn" onClick="calc();" />

Answere: 
<input type="text" id="result" size="5"/>

Comment: sorry, accidentally hit the post button. The above is the html for the script if that helps. How would I go about to that what you told me to do?

Comment: @user1985551: Inside the `calc()` function, type `doCalc();`. You can actually put it anywhere inside, like after the `var result;` line. If that doesn't work, then your `calc()` function probably isn't global.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use `.value` on form fields and `.innerHTML` on everything else (`span`s, `p`s, etc.). `.innerHTML` gets or sets the inside of an element.

Also, make sure that the submit button has an event handler for `onclick`--the easiest method is `<input onclick="doCalc();" ... />`.

Answer (score 0):

I would try decoupling the calc() function.  Here is one way to go about it.

```
var Calculator = {
    "eval" : function(operator, x, y) {
                 switch( operator ) {
                     case "+":
                         return (x + y);
                     case "-":
                         return (x - y);
                 }
             }
}
```

Better yet,

```
    var Calculator = {
    "eval" : function(operator) {
                 var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
                 args.splice(0,1); // lazy hack to remove the argument for the operator

                 switch( operator ) {
                     case "+":
                         return args.reduce( function(x,y){ return (x + y); } );
                     case "-":
                         return args.reduce( function(x,y){ return (x - y) } );
                 }
             }
}
```

This way it's much easier to re-use and test.

```
var answer = Calculator.eval( '+', 20, 20, 2 );  // yay, prefix notation
```

The second variation uses the higher order function 'reduce' that reduces an array into a single value.

Here are the steps on how reduce works. I've pulled out the lambda function to make things a little more clear.

```
var arr = [20, 20, 20];
function sum(x, y){ return (x + y); }

function reduceMagic(arr){
    var temp = sum(arr[0], arr[1]);  // temp -> 40
    temp =  sum(temp, arr[2]);       // temp -> 42
    return temp;
}
```